# How to mark a parallel path of existing line in JOSM/QGIS?

Tags: josm, maperitive

I have a railway line imported from OSM to JOSM. This is converted as map tile (using maperitive) for web mapping in leaflet. Now I want to mark a parallel line to the existing railway line.
For example. A railway line (curved) is having a distance of 10 km. Say from 4th km to 6th km if some work has been done, it should be marked with different colour in the web map.
How to do it?